# load django templates according to app

Tags: django, django-templates

### Problem

According to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#using-subdirectories), the template loader 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader' loads the templates by searching in the [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-INSTALLED_APPS) and

> ... and will use the one it finds first.

However, I'm struggling to understand why this is consistent with django's spirit of having self-contained apps. Let's take a look at an example.

#### Example

Consider using the django-"preferable" approach of [templates subdirectories](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#using-subdirectories).

```
root/
-manage.py
-main/settings.py
-main/urls.py
-main/views.py
-main/templates/base.html
-main/templates/base/header.html
-main/templates/base/secondary_header.html
-main/app1/base_extension.html
-main/app1/base/secondary_header.html
```

naturally with **init**.py in main/ and main/app1/.

Since I'm using the standard template directory name, I just need to use the app_directories.Loader in [TEMPLATE_LOADERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS).

Consider the following base.html and base_extension.html:

```
#base.html
{% include "header.html" %}
{% block secondary_header %}{% include "base/secondary_header.html" %}{% endblock %}

#base_extension.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block secondary_header %}{% include "base/secondary_header.html" %}{% endblock %}
```

In the spirit of django, I would expect that if the base.html is rendered, it uses main's secondary_header (main/templates/base/header.html), but if base_extension.html is rendered, the secondary_header.html should be the specific one from app1 (main/app1/base/secondary_header.html). This does not happens due to the quoted text above.

This issue can be dangerous, as well pointed out in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#using-subdirectories)

> The order of [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-INSTALLED_APPS) is significant!

as an installed app on top (in the INSTALLED_APPS) of the app of the main page of the website can "overload" their templates if there is template name collision.

This makes django's app system a little "odd", since each app must have templates that don't collide with others, even if the programer knows, due to hierarchic structure of directories, which templates belong to which app.

### Question

Is there any way to solve this issue? Was this issue discussed in Django community or is there any loader around that solves this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply prefix your app templates with your app's name. This is best practice in many ways, and it will solve this problem as well. I use the following structure:

```
project/app1/templates/app1__base.html
project/app1/templates/app1__header.html
project/app1/templates/app1_main.html
project/templates/_base.html
project/templates/_header.html
project/app2/templates/app2__base.html
```